# Pyinstaller not compiling joblib

Tags: pyinstaller, joblib

I've got code that loads a joblib file and works perfectly in my IDE. However when making an exe with pyinstaller it fails. This is some test code:

```
 from joblib import load
 print('imported joblib')
 load('Repeat.joblib')
```

When running the exe it successfully imports load, but fails when reading the joblib file. The joblib file is a machine learning model build using scikit learn 0.22.1 and I have joblib 0.14.1.

I've tried everything I can think of. Pyinstaller initially failed with a recursion error but I fixed that using a spec file using
     import sys
     sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

A, I did find this post about people rolling back Joblib to v0.11 with some success. However that doesn't appear to have resolved your issue.

IT might be an issue with PyInstaller. The key might lie in your `hiddenimports'.

[Bounty Source solution](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/70003153-pyinstaller-exe-keeps-opening-itself)